# Collect google form results in a single google sheet in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I used google script to generate a list of forms with the same structure but different content. I would like to collect the responses for each form and merge them into a single google sheet. Is there any way to do so in google scripts?

Comment: Would you explain what you mean by "merge"? the data might be merged using a `query` function, or a script might create a sheet holding the static results of the various responses. Which do you want?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be having the same script in each Form. Use the [Form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events) event to add a new row in the same Sheet every time a user submits a response. All the scripts can reference the same Sheet by using the Id with the [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) method.

Then, the simplest way to put the data into the sheet would be using the [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) method.

For example:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var sprSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('your sheet id');
  var sheet = sprsheet.getSheetByName('your sheet name');

  //Store the values from your form
  var values = {value1: e.namedValues['formValue1'][0], value2: e.namedValues['formValue2'][0]};

  //This would write value1 and value2 into Columns A and B respectively
  sheet.appendRow([values[0].value1, values[0].value2]);

}
```

You might also take a look at the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms) to manage Responses for Google Forms.